# wordpress - how to get an array of templates of an specific theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update a wordpress plugin. At current time the plugin code displays:

```
$themes = get_themes();
$theme = get_current_theme();
$templates = $themes[$theme]['Template Files'];
```

Here the problem is that `get_theme()` and `get_themes()` are deprecated, and I have tried to change it to `wp_get_theme()`, and `wp_get_themes()`, but it doesnt work.

Does anyone have any idea how to update this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owww... I found out how it is!!!...

```
  $theme = wp_get_theme();
  $templates = $theme->{'Template Files'};
```

hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: Just to point out that `$themes = wp_get_themes();` is not used in your case.